# What does it mean to say that the electric potential of a system of point charges is, say 5V?

Tags: electric-fields, potential-energy, gauss-law

For example, what does it mean to say that the electric potential of an electrically charged plate (not an infinitely large plate)  is 5V without any mention of which point on the plane we're referring to? Is it possible that the electric potential of all points on the surface of the plate are the same? If so how is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It will be true that the entire surface of the plate is at the same electric potential (w.r.t. ground) if the plate is a conductor. A good conductor allows electrons to move around and rearrange themselves so that this will always be the case. In essence, an electric field must be perpendicular to a conductor which means that the surface of the conductor must be an equipotential surface (i.e. the gradient of the potential along the surface - the electric field pointing in directions along the surface - must be 0). You can see this previous question for why this must be the case: [Why is the electric field perpendicular to every point on the surface of a conductor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74456/why-is-the-electric-field-perpendicular-to-every-point-on-the-surface-of-a-condu)