# What is electric field vector?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, vector-fields

What is electric field vector? How to find out the Electric Field vector at a point on a equipotential surface. Please explain by giving an example.

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! This site is for asking conceptual questions about physics. This question seems to be mostly about definitions - have you checked [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_field)? If you're following lecture notes or a textbook this should also be explained clearly there.

Comment: Some of the answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/74456/why-is-the-electric-field-perpendicular-to-every-point-on-the-surface-of-a-condu) might be relevant to you.

Answer (score 2):

> What is electric field vector?

The electric field vector is a mathematical description of the *magnitude* and the *direction* of the electric field.

> How to find out the Electric Field vector at a point on a equipotential surface.

The electric field is given by the negative gradient of the potential

$$\vec{E}=-\vec\nabla V$$

Knowing you have an equipotential surface tells you that there is no component of the gradient in certain directions, and therefore restrict the direction of $\vec{E}$ to two possible choices. But it doesn't tell you anything about the magnitude of $\vec{E}$.

Comment: Why are you talking about *magnetic* field? Twice?

Comment: @G.Smith, thanks. Fixed